# How do you "DependsOn" a Lambda function from a CFN resource?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

In Serverless, I am creating an `AWS::Lambda::Permission` CFN resource that allows Cognito to invoke a [Custom Message Lambda Handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html).

`AWS::Lambda::Permission` depends on the lambda. How do I ensure that the lambda is created first?

I have already tried adding a `DependsOn` property to the `AWS::Lambda::Permission` CFN resource with no luck.

Below is my CFN resource that is trying to add permissions to Cognito to invoke a lambda:

```
UserPoolLambdaInvokePermission:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
    Action: lambda:invokeFunction
    Principal: cognito-idp.amazonaws.com
    FunctionName: arn:aws:lambda:${self:provider.region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:function:${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-cognitoCustomMessage
    SourceArn: arn:aws:cognito-idp:${self:provider.region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:userpool/${self:provider.environment.USER_POOL_ID}
```

Here is what my lambda looks like in my `serverless.yml`:

```
cognitoCustomMessage:
  handler: src/main/lambdas/users_handler.cognitoCustomMessage
```

Here is what my lambda is doing on a very basic level:

```
cognitoCustomMessage(event, next) {
  if (event.triggerSource === 'CustomMessage_ForgotPassword') {
    // do stuff
  }
  return next(null, event);
}
```

The error I get from the above is:

> An error occurred: CognitoCustomMessageLambdaFunction - Function not
>   found:
>   arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:1234567890:my-service-dev-cognitoCustomMessage
>   (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 404; Error Code:
>   ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID:
>   e2a98525-5090-4d0f-a1f5-20610474f93b).

If I add a `DependsOn`:

```
UserPoolLambdaInvokePermission:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  DependsOn: arn:aws:lambda:${self:provider.region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:function:${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-cognitoCustomMessage
  ...
  ....
```

The error I get from above is:

> The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error:
>   DependsOn must be a string or list of strings.

I have also tried:

```
UserPoolLambdaInvokePermission:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  DependsOn: CognitoCustomMessageLambdaFunction
  ...
  ....
```

The error I get from above is:

> An error occurred: CognitoCustomMessageLambdaFunction - Function not
>   found:
>   arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:1234567890:my-service-dev-cognitoCustomMessage
>   (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 404; Error Code:
>   ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID:
>   b888ae82-a0d7-4d69-888e-9e63027925c1).

I expect that there should be some method to create a lambda function first prior to the CFN resource needing to use it, but this does not seem to be the case with `DependsOn`.

Comment: You should include the basic declaration of the Lambda function in your post.

Comment: @jarmod I have added a small snippet of my lambda

Comment: @JeffreyWen Hey Jeffrey, I'm having a similar issue that you had, what did you write in your Properties ? the arn in the `FunctionName`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The DependsOn attribute should have the logical name of the Lambda Function in the Cloud formation template not the ARN of Lambda Function. For example, if your Lambda function's logical name in the Cloud Formation template is MyLambda then DependsOn should be like this:

```
UserPoolLambdaInvokePermission:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  DependsOn: MyLambda
```

NOTE: open cloud formation template `.serverless/cloudformation-template-update-stack.json` and look for *logical* lambda function name.

Example:

```json
{
    "MonitorLambdaFunction": {
    "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
    "Properties": {
      "Code": {
        "S3Bucket": "deploy-dev",
        "S3Key": "serverless/dev/1641551717730-2022-01-07T10:35:17.730Z/zip"
      },
      "Handler": "src/monitors/handler.devMonitor",
      "Runtime": "nodejs14.x",
      "FunctionName": "dev-monitor",
      "MemorySize": 1024,
      "Timeout": 6,
      "Environment": {
        "Variables": {
          "STAGE": "dev",
        }
      },
      "Role": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "monitorIamRoleLambdaExecution",
          "Arn"
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

`MonitorLambdaFunction` is the name you are looking for.

Comment: I create my lambda function in `serverless.yml`. I have updated the original post with what happens if I change `DependsOn` to the logical ID of the lambda.

Comment: Can you share a snippet of your lambda function along with the permission resource? From what I am seeing, you have named you lambda as "cognitoCustomMessage" and in DependsOn you have written "CognitoCustomMessageLambdaFunction".

Comment: The "DependsOn" property does work. The issue that I was getting was related to the fact I deleted my lambda previously. Therefore, SLS/CFN will run an update process and still think it's there. Simply changing the lambda function's name/logical id's name made it work.

Answer (score 10):

Your function defined in serverless.yml is converted into a cloudformation resource under the hood. The resource is called XLambdaFunction where X = The name of your function with the first letter capitalized.

So if you have:

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    ...other function stuff...
```

You can reference:

```
DependsOn: HelloLambdaFunction
```

I can only assume that if your function is already named `CognitoCustomMessageLambdaFunction` then you would have to reference:

```
DependsOn: CognitoCustomMessageLambdaFunctionLambdaFunction
```

Comment: This is perfect answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue, adding dependsOn key worked for me.